# Plot labels go outside of box

Tags: plotting

I have the following code which I used to draw a 3D plot. The problem is that the labels {x,y,z} go out of the box and so it looks bad. Is it possible to to changing the location of 'x', 'y', and 'z'? or perhaps any better ways?

```
P0={0,0,0}; P1={1,0,0}; P2={0,1,0}; P3={0,0,1}; P4={1,1,1}; P5={-1,-1,-1};    

R[1]=ConvexHullMesh[{P0,P1,P2,P3},
       Frame->True,
       PlotRange -> Automatic,
       MeshCellStyle -> {{2,All} -> Opacity[.4, Red],{1,All} -> Black,{0,All} -> Blue}]

Show[Region[R[1], PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2},{-1.2,1.2}}, 
  Axes -> True,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  AxesOrigin -> {0,0,0},
  LabelStyle -> {8,Bold,Black}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x,y,z},
  AxesStyle -> Thick,
  Boxed->True]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be more to your liking:

```
Show[Region[R[1], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> True,
   ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {16, Bold, Black}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}, {0.5, 1}}, 
  AxesStyle -> Thick, Boxed -> True, ViewPoint -> Front]]
```

[image: pic]